# How to use data from multiple similar columns as rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

| ItemName | 1mth_presale_cost | 2mth_presale_cost | 1mth_postsale_cost | 2mth_postsale_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10.1 | 12.1 | 12.5 | 15.1 |
| 1001 | 20.2 | 15.2 | 25.2 | 17.3 |

I want the result to be like below table:

| ItemName | 1mth_cost | 2mth_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10.1 | 12.1 |
| 1000 | 12.5 | 15.1 |
| 1001 | 20.2 | 15.2 |
| 1001 | 25.2 | 17.3 |

I don't want to use UNION for this.

Comment: And why you don't want to use `UNION`!?

Comment: Just figuring out if there is any other way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First each row converted into two sets then apply conditional CASE statement for getting desired result.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT t.ItemName
     , CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN [1mth_presale_cost] ELSE [1mth_postsale_cost] END  "1mth_cost"
     , CASE WHEN p.id = 1 THEN [2mth_presale_cost] ELSE [2mth_postsale_cost] END  "2mth_cost"
FROM test t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2 id) p
ORDER BY t.ItemName, p.id
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e1fdaf829c39554941c068b0c8a3e04

Answer (score 0):

You want to *unpivot* the data.  In SQL Server, you can use `cross apply`:

```
select t.ItemName, v.1mth_cost, v.2mth_cost
from t cross apply
     (values (t.1mth_presale_cost, t.2mth_presale_cost, 'presale'),
             (t.1mth_postsale_cost, t.2mth_postsale_cost, 'postsale')
     ) v(1mth_cost, 2mth_cost, which);
```

Note that this you can also include `which` to see which of the columns is being used for each row.