# Formatting output of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a query result of two columns that looks like this

```
name      text
---------------
John      hello
Carl      hi
Doe       my text
Alice     another text
```

I would like to find a way how to format this result as a text. What I need is this output:

```
John:
hello
_____
Carl:
hi
_____
Doe:
my text
_____
Alice:
another text
_____
```

So in other words I need to take the first column's value as a text, append some text to it, append second column's value as a text and append some more text. And do that for every row.

Is there an easy way of how to do this using only SQL Server's syntax?

EDIT: I am only using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I need the whole result as a plain text. I was thinking of writing a function that would return it?

EDIT2: I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're expecting as a resultset; is that a single row and single column? This looks like a job for your application code tbh.

Comment: As per requirement two column value of a row will show two rows and one column. Right? if so then please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328675/how-to-use-data-from-multiple-similar-columns-as-rows-in-sql/69328841#69328841

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that I need just one text value for the whole result.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Do you assume that "John" precedes "Carl" precedes "Doe" etc.? If so, your goal may be impossible as rows in a table are, by definition, unordered.

Comment: @Stu It's SQL Server 2016

Comment: @SMor my query returns the values ordered by date created, so they should always be in the same order

Comment: The fact that they *always* did return in that order is not an indication that they always do so in the future, you *need* an `order by` clause

Answer (score 1):

Simple string aggregation should do the trick

```sql
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT(
    name,
    ':
',
    text,
    '
_____'  
  ) AS nvarchar(max)), '
')

FROM YourTable
```

Or for SQL Server 2016 or earlier, you can use `FOR XML` aggregation

```sql
SELECT STUFF((
  SELECT
    CONCAT('
',
      name,
      ':
',
      text,
      '
_____')
  FROM YourTable
  FOR XML PATH, TYPE
).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Unfortunately my SQL Server version (2016) does not seem to support this. Do you know of any alternative?

Comment: OK done that now